# Grunt Multiple tasks with same module do not run

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

My current gruntfile looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function( grunt ) {
  require('time-grunt')( grunt );

  grunt.initConfig({
    vNo: 'v1',
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    filepath: '',
    directory: ''
  });

  grunt.loadTasks('grunt/tasks');
  grunt.loadTasks('grunt/configs');
};
```

When I run `grunt scsslint` it runs fine.

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
  grunt.config('scsslint', {
    options: {
      configFile: '.scss-lint.yml',
      reporterOutput: 'scss-lint-report.xml',
      colorizeOutput: true,
      maxBuffer: 30000000000000000000 * 1024
    },
    src: ['src/bbtcom/_assets/scss/**/*']
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-scss-lint');
};
```

If I try to run `grunt scsslintCalcs` I get an error,

```
Warning: Task "scsslintCalcs" not found. Use --force to continue.
Error: Task "scsslintCalcs" not found.
at Task.run (/Users/Development/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:179:28)
at /Users/Development/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:161:39
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/Development/projecy/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:161:9)
at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/Development/project/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:44:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

but my `scsslintCalcs.js`

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
  grunt.config('scsslintCalcs', {
    options: {
      configFile: '.scss-lint.yml',
      reporterOutput: 'scss-lint-report-calcs.xml',
      colorizeOutput: true,
      maxBuffer: 30000000000000000000 * 1024
    },
    src: ['src/leadfusion/*.scss']
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-scss-lint');
};
```

So I'm not sure why `scsslint` works but not the rest.

any insight as to what is going wrong?

I've tried removing `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-scss-lint');` from the tasks even renaming them to just `scsslint` but keeping the file what I need with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't registering the task like I thought I was.

`grunt.registerTask('scsslintCalcs', function () {});`